# Definition of Base Change of representation

Tags: rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms

Recently, I read the paper on Ichino-Ikeda conjecture for unitary groups by Raphaël Beuzart-Plessis (**https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.06538.pdf**). In the introduction, it says that

> Let $BC(\Pi)$ be the base change of $\Pi$ to $GL_n(\mathbb{A}_E)\times GL_{n+1}(\mathbb{A}_E)$
>   (known to exist thanks to the recent work of Mok and Kaletha, Minguez, Shin
>   and White).

where $\Pi$ is a cuspidal automorphic representation of $U(n)\times U(n+1)(\mathbb{A}_F)$. $E$ and $F$ are number field, and $E$ is a quadratic extension of $F$.

I am a bit confused about the conception of base change. It seems that it is a general conception. Thank you if you can tell me the general definition of the base change of automorphic representation using the representation language.

Comment: Do you know what it is for a single unitary group?  On the product it will just be the product.  What it conjecturally is is explained in many expositions of automorphic representations, e.g., Arthur-Gelbart.